# K8s - not working L2 Advertising of Metallb

Tags: networking, load-balancing, kubernetes

I'm installing 1 node k8s cluster and can't reach metallb IP address from same subnet.

```
CRI = Containerd 1.6 
CNI = Flannel. 
control-plane taint is disabled 
Pod CIDR = 10.244.0.0/16 
Cluster CIDR = 10.105.107.0/24 
Kube-proxy mode - IPVS with strictArp "true"
```

my metallb config manifest:

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
name: first-pool
namespace: metallb-system
spec:
addresses:

- 10.105.107.224/27
```

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
name: first-advertisement
namespace: metallb-system
spec:
ipAddressPools:

- first-pool
```

When I'm creating service(ingress-nginx, e.g.) - IP address assigns correctly and I can connect them from my node via curl 10.105.107.224
But I don't see announced event in    `kubectl describe svc`    (only IP Assigned event). This mean that curl from any other host in same subnet and broadcast domain is not working, also as arping not working too.
I also don't see any WARNING's or ERROR's on speaker's side. I saw different topics with this theme and twice re-checked my subnets, configs and other, but no idea.
Logs from controller:

Logs from speaker:

```
{"caller":"config_controller.go:150","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"/default","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:58","controller":"ConfigReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/ingress-nginx","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:150","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"/ingress-nginx","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:58","controller":"ConfigReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/kube-flannel","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:150","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"/kube-flannel","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:58","controller":"ConfigReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/kube-node-lease","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:150","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"/kube-node-lease","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:58","controller":"ConfigReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/kube-public","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:150","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"/kube-public","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:17Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller.go:64","controller":"ServiceReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"metallb-system/webhook-service","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:26Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller.go:115","controller":"ServiceReconciler","end reconcile":"metallb-system/webhook-service","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:26Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:58","controller":"ConfigReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"metallb-system/first-pool","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:167","controller":"ConfigReconciler","event":"force service reload","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:178","controller":"ConfigReconciler","event":"config reloaded","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:179","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"metallb-system/first-pool","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller_reload.go:63","controller":"ServiceReconciler - reprocessAll","level":"info","start reconcile":"metallbreload/reload","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller_reload.go:119","controller":"ServiceReconciler - reprocessAll","end reconcile":"metallbreload/reload","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller.go:64","controller":"ServiceReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller.go:115","controller":"ServiceReconciler","end reconcile":"ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:58","controller":"ConfigReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"metallb-system/first-advertisement","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:167","controller":"ConfigReconciler","event":"force service reload","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:178","controller":"ConfigReconciler","event":"config reloaded","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"config_controller.go:179","controller":"ConfigReconciler","end reconcile":"metallb-system/first-advertisement","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller_reload.go:63","controller":"ServiceReconciler - reprocessAll","level":"info","start reconcile":"metallbreload/reload","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"service_controller_reload.go:119","controller":"ServiceReconciler - reprocessAll","end reconcile":"metallbreload/reload","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:40:33Z"}
{"caller":"node_controller.go:46","controller":"NodeReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/k8s-1","ts":"2024-03-17T18:44:32Z"}
{"caller":"speakerlist.go:274","level":"info","msg":"triggering discovery","op":"memberDiscovery","ts":"2024-03-17T18:44:32Z"}
{"caller":"node_controller.go:69","controller":"NodeReconciler","end reconcile":"/k8s-1","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:44:32Z"}
{"caller":"node_controller.go:46","controller":"NodeReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/k8s-1","ts":"2024-03-17T18:49:39Z"}
{"caller":"speakerlist.go:274","level":"info","msg":"triggering discovery","op":"memberDiscovery","ts":"2024-03-17T18:49:39Z"}
{"caller":"node_controller.go:69","controller":"NodeReconciler","end reconcile":"/k8s-1","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:49:39Z"}
{"caller":"node_controller.go:46","controller":"NodeReconciler","level":"info","start reconcile":"/k8s-1","ts":"2024-03-17T18:54:45Z"}
{"caller":"speakerlist.go:274","level":"info","msg":"triggering discovery","op":"memberDiscovery","ts":"2024-03-17T18:54:45Z"}
{"caller":"node_controller.go:69","controller":"NodeReconciler","end reconcile":"/k8s-1","level":"info","ts":"2024-03-17T18:54:45Z"}
```

Comment: Are your controller logs actually empty or is there a copy/paste problem in your question?

Comment: @larsks,  yep, it's a problem of copy/paste, but I finished with this problem by switching to OpenELB - it's configured perfectly from first time as a magic